# Which is preferable - printf or fprintf

Tags: c, printf, output

I know that both of the functions can be used to output to the console.
I read [**that question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627330/difference-between-fprintf-printf-sprintf), but no one didn't tell which is prefered to be used when outputing to the console.
So which function is better, are there any major differences?

Comment: It is up to you. You are the programmer. You set the preference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To quote the standard (7.21.6.3 in n1570):

> The `printf` function is equivalent to `fprintf` with the argument `stdout` interposed
>   before the arguments to `printf`.

So `printf` is more convenient when printing to the console, otherwise, there's no difference. But `fprintf` is a bit easier to modify if you want to change the output target.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not always the case, the ARM v7 LEDE toolchain will circumvent printf, while fprintf(stdout, ...)  will work properly.

Comment: That means it's not a conforming implementation, doesn't it?

Answer (score 8):

Each process has an input stream, named `stdin` and two output streams, `stdout` and `stderr`. These output streams are both connected to your terminal so the following commands will all print the line "hello" to your terminal:

```
printf("hello\n");
fprintf(stdout, "hello\n");

fprintf(stderr, "hello\n");
```

The first two are exactly the same, the first just being shorter and more convenient. The first is most commonly used.

The third is different in that the content sent to `stderr` is logically separate from that sent to `stdout`.  It is usually used for error messages that you want the user to see.  The library function `perror` prints its error messages to `stderr`.

The significance of the `stderr` stream being logically separate is that its content can be separated from `stdout`.  For example, say we use the command `ls -l` to list a file.

```
$ touch myfile
$ ls -l myfile
-rw-r--r--  1 wrm  staff  0  6 Nov 20:44 myfile
```

Now if we redirect the output of `ls` to another file, we see the following:

```
$ ls -l myfile > otherfile
$
```

There is no output printed because the `>` redirected the `stdout` stream of the `ls` process to `otherfile`.  You can see the output it redirected by looking at `otherfile`:

```
$ cat otherfile 
-rw-r--r--  1 wrm  staff  0  6 Nov 20:44 myfile
$
```

But the `>` did not redirect the `stderr` stream.  You can test that by removing `myfile` and re-running the redirected `ls -l` command:

```
$ rm myfile
$ ls -l myfile > otherfile
ls: myfile: No such file or directory
$
```

So here you can see that although `stdout` was redirected to `otherfile` , `stderr` was not redirected and so its content appeared on the terminal.  Also note that `otherfile` is now empty because the `ls` command did not find `myfile` and so there was nothing to send to `stdout`.

It is also possible to redirect `stderr`, but it depends upon your shell (the program that controls your terminal) how that is done.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to print to a particular output stream, use fprintf.

If you need to show an error message, use fprintf w/ stderr

If you're developing a command-line executable and just want to display something to the user, use printf.