# Confusion about how the sprintf function works in C

Tags: c

I'm confused because I thought the sprintf function returned a string, and it shows on cplusplus.com that it returns an int? Why?

Basically, I'm having trouble with the following line, where I'm trying to pad some spacing and format a string simultaneously:

```
printf("%30s", sprintf("1.10f", modeTimeTotal/num_tests));
```

There error I get is:

```
cannot convert 'double' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)'
```

Comment: Check this post out: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627330/difference-between-fprintf-printf-sprintf

Comment: *"Confusion about how the sprintf function works in C"* **Why the `C++` tag?**

Comment: @Manu343726: Retagged

Answer (score 5):

`sprintf` prints *into* a string an returns the number of characters so printed.  The first argument to the `sprintf` call should be the string to print into:

```
char buffer[30];
int n = sprintf(buffer, "%1.10f", modeTimeTotal/num_tests);
printf("Printed %d characters.  String is '%s'\n", n, buffer);
```

You're getting the warning you are because you're trying to shoehorn the `modeTimeTotal/num_tests` into the format string argument to `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

sprintf() returns the number of characters printed (not including the NUL terminator byte).

You should use it like this:

```
char buf[512];
sprintf(buf, "%30s%1.10f", "", modeTimeTotal/num_tests);
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Comment: [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) "Return Value
On success, the total number of characters written is returned. This count does not include the additional null-character automatically appended at the end of the string.
On failure, a negative number is returned."