# What is the naming convention behind stdio functions (sprintf, vsprintf and fprintf)?

Tags: c, naming-conventions, stdout

An article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627330/difference-between-fprintf-printf-and-sprintf) explains the differences which many of us have known for years. My assumptions have been:

- **`sprintf`**

  - First character "s" is for first argument of type string.
  - Last character "f" is for format?
- **`fprintf`**

  - First character "f" is for first argument of type string.
  - Last character "f" is for format?
- **`printf`**

  - starts with "" for no first argument.
  - Last character "f" is for format?

I would think the first letter is for the first argument, but `vsprintf` and `printf` deny this claim. The last letter seems to mean it takes a format. Not to mention all the other uses of U's, N's, C's, V's and F's.

It would be amazing if someone could give **explanation** and **source** to the rational behind all these conventions in `stdio`.

**BONUS** - 
Get additional respect for name dropping.

Comment: `fprintf()` writes to a filestream. The leading `f`stand for *file*. The final `f` really stands for *formatted*.

Comment: @pid Thank you for your comment. Those were similar assumptions I've had. I could be wrong, but I think most people agree on what they stand for. I'm really looking for the rational, such as "is this part of a bigger naming convention?" and the source material, such as "Who wrote it?".

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much the first character that you need to look at, but rather the *prefix*.

The "original" function, `printf` is for formatted printing.  One or more prefixes can then be added to the `printf` name:

- `f`: print to a `FILE`
- `s`: print to a string
- `v`: print with `va_list`
- `n`: print a given number of characters
- `w`: print wide characters:

So that gives us:

- `printf`: formatted printing to stdout
- `fprintf`: formatted printing to a `FILE`
- `sprintf`: formatted printing to a string
- `snprintf`: formatted printing to a string with a given number of characters
- `vprintf`: formatted printing with `va_list` to stdout
- `vfprintf`: formatted printing with `va_list` to a `FILE`
- `vsprintf`: formatted printing with `va_list` to a string
- `vsnprintf`: formatted printing with `va_list` to a string with a given number of characters
- `wprintf`: formatted printing of wide characters to stdout
- `fwprintf`: formatted printing of wide characters to a `FILE`
- `swprintf`: formatted printing of wide characters to a string
- `vwprintf`: formatted printing of wide characters with `va_list` to stdout
- `vfwprintf`: formatted printing of wide characters with `va_list` to a `FILE`
- `vswprintf`: formatted printing of wide characters  with `va_list` to a string

Comment: Don't forget w: wide. :-)

Comment: 1) `swprintf` and `vswprintf` also "with a given number of characters" even though they lack an `n`.  2) Consider A-Z sort. (except `printf`)

Answer (score 1):

**Prefixes:**

1. `N` - provides a safety net for limiting the number of characters it can safely write/read from.
2. `V` - you're using variable arguments list. This is useful if you want to write functions that emulate printf.
3. `S` - you're reading/writing from/to a string.
4. `F` - you're reading/writing from/to file.
5. `P` - you're reading from the a process's output
6. `None` - printf and scanf don't have prefixes as they're just reading/writing from standard input/output -  which are nothing but files in the UNIX world anyway.

**Suffixes:**

1. `F` - You're reading and writing in terms of formatted output (You're saying that you'll use a format string followed by variable arguments)
2. `C` - You're dealing with characters one at a time.
3. `S` - You're dealing with strings (the quantity is almost always till you reach the next whitespace character).
4. `W` - You're dealing with words (don't confuse this with english words, word just means the sizeof(int))